# source.list empty in ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

why is source.list empty in the new version of ubuntu? where did they move it to? (the file exists because it is suggested with tab)

```
 sudo gedit etc/apt/sources.list
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have tried to open etc folder which command line thought it is located in home (~). Use absolute path with /, i.e. /etc/apt/sources.list. Or go to / using `cd /` and then `etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the sources.list file open the terminal and type:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Note that I used sudoedit to edit sources.list in the default terminal editor instead of gedit, because you shouldn't use normal `sudo` to start graphical applications as root. The correct path to sources.list is `/etc/apt/sources.list` not `etc/apt/sources.list`

The instructions for using the default nano text editor are always found at the bottom of every page. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Comment: But you can use `sudo -H` to open graphical applications... ie: `sudo -H gedit filename`.

Comment: For a new user it's best to keep it simple to begin with, especially a new user who has already taught himself how to do it the wrong way.

Comment: And `control-o, enter, control-x` is easier for a new user, than `Save` and `Quit` from a menu in gedit? Give a fish to a hungry man and he's feed for a day, but give him a fishing pole, and brief instruction, and he's fed for life.

Comment: Once you've tried it the nice way you'll never forget how to do it because the instructions for using the default nano text editor are always found at the bottom of every page. You don't have to remember any code, just that it's there at the bottom of the page.